# How do I calculate the standard error of the ACF if the errors are t-distributed?

Tags: confidence-interval, arima, t-distribution

I am modeling my data with ARIMA and to check if my model is good I have to compute the residuals and plot the correlation function and partial correlation function of the residuals. If the results of the functions are between $1.96 \pm 1/\sqrt(\sigma)$ that means that the residuals are drawn from Gaussian process, hence my model is good (there are more processes needed to be done to check the model, but I'm not worried about those now).

Now, suppose to model my data I have used ARIMA with innovation comes from t-distribution. If now I compute the residuals and plot the autocorrelation and partial correlation function, does it still need to be between $1.96 \pm 1/\sqrt(\sigma)$?

I guess I have to find what is the 95%  confidence of t-distribution and that would be my boundary! Am I right? 
And the second question is how can I standardize the residuals, knowing that they have t-distribution.